# Summing a ledger over long period of time. (reconciliation, snapshots, rolling sum?)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

We are building a warehouse stock management system and have a stock movements table that records stock into, through and out of the system, for each product and each location it is stored. i.e.

- 10 units of Product A is received into Location A
- 10 units Product A are moved to Location B and removed from Location A.
- 1 unit is removed (sold) from Location B

... and so on.

This means that over to work out how much of each product is stored in each location we would;

```
"SELECT SUM('qty') FROM stock_movements GROUP BY location, product"
```

(we actually use Eloquent but I have used SQL for an example)

Over time, this will mean our stock movements table will grow to millions of rows and I am wondering the way to best manage this. The options I can think of:

- Sum the rows as grouped above and accept it may get slow over time. Im not sure how many rows it will take before it actually starts to cause any performance issues. When requesting a whole inventory log via our API each row would have to be summed for every product, so this will compile to a fairly large calculation.
- Create a snapshot of the summed rows every day/week/month etc. on a cron and then just add the sum of the most recent rows on the fly.
- Create a separate table with a live stock level which is added to and subtracted with every stock movement. The stock movements table shows an entire history of all movements while the new table just shows the live amounts. We would use database transactions here to ensure they keep in sync.

Is there a defined and best practice way to handle this kind of thing already? Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that your system is already where a lot of people say the database world should be moving: event sourcing. ES just stores every event against an object, in this case your location, and in order to get the current state you have to start with an empty object and replay all of that objects events.

Of course, this can be time-consuming, and your last two bullet points are the standard ways of dealing with it. First, you can create regular snapshots with the current-as-of-then totals for that location, and then when someone asks for the current-as-of-now totals you only need to replay events since the last snapshot. Second, you can have a separate table of current values, and whenever you insert a record into your event store you also update the current value. If they ever get out-of-sync, you can always start fresh and replay the entire event series again.

Both of these scenarios are typically managed through an intermediary queue service, like SQL's Service Broker, RabbitMQ, or Amazon's SQS: instead of inserting an event directly into your event store, you send the change into a queue and the code that processes the queue will update your snapshot.

Good luck!